# Excel VBA (userform) about ListBox

Tags: excel, listbox

Is it possible to use a listbox to change the order of rows in a worksheet? I have searched the Web for about an hour without ressults. I am using the following code for the task:

```
 Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
 ListBox1.RowSource = "Sheet1!A1:A15"
 End Sub

 Option Explicit 
 Const UP As Integer = -1 
 Const DOWN As Integer = 1 

 Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinUp() 

If Me.ListBox1.ListCount > 1 Then 
    Call MoveListItem(UP, Me.ListBox1) 
End If 

End Sub 

Private Sub SpinButton1_SpinDown() 

If Me.ListBox1.ListCount > 1 Then 
    Call MoveListItem(DOWN, Me.ListBox1) 
End If 

End Sub 

Private Sub MoveListItem(ByVal intDirection As Integer, _ 
ByRef ListBox1 As ListBox) 

Dim intNewPosition As Integer 
Dim strTemp As String 

intNewPosition = ListBox1.ListIndex + intDirection 
strTemp = ListBox1.List(intNewPosition) 

If intNewPosition > -1 _ 
And intNewPosition < ListBox1.ListCount Then 

     'Swap listbox items
    ListBox1.List(intNewPosition) = ListBox1.Value 
    ListBox1.List(intNewPosition - intDirection) = strTemp 
    ListBox1.Selected(intNewPosition) = True 

End If 

End Sub
```

Hope somone can give me a hint!

**UPDATE!!**

What i want is, if I for example have these values in a column in my worksheet:

week1

week2

week3

week4

Then I would like to re-arrenge the order of these values with the SpinButton in the ListBox;

week2

week4

week1

week3

Comment: What do you mean change order of rows? sorting? can you provide a before and after of your data? that would help us know what you are looking to do.

Comment: @guitarthrower I have updated my question, hope you kan help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You most certainly can do that!

Here is a quick code that does this in general, I will leave it to you to place this where it is needed:

```
For i = 0 To ListBox1.ListCount - 1
    ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & CStr(i + 1)).Value = ListBox1.List(i)
Next i
```

You'll probably need to change what is inside the for loop to better reflect your own code. For writing to a specific range just add whatever starting row number you want!